# Azure SignalR - pass multiple params to connection.invoke

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, azure-signalr

I've been using the below code and it has been working fine for about a year.

```
    public async Task JoinGroup(string group)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }
    connection.on("UserConnected", function (connectionId) {
         connection.invoke("JoinGroup", groupName).catch(function (err) {
             return console.error(err.toString());
    });
});
```

However I've recently decided I want to add a bool to the call and as soon as I add another parameter, the call always fails with
**Failed to invoke 'JoinGroup' due to an error on the server.**

All I want to add is

```
    public async Task JoinGroup(string group, bool hasSession)
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }

     var hasSession = false;
     connection.on("UserConnected", function (connectionId) {
         connection.invoke("JoinGroup", groupName, hasSession).catch(function (err) {
             return console.error(err.toString());
         });
     });
```

Comment: What is the error you see on the app-server side? You can set option [EnableDetailedErrors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.huboptions.enabledetailederrors?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to get what the detailed error is. It might be that you have multiple app server instances connected to the SignalR service, some of them are in old version while some of them are in new version. And the clients are routed to the old version app server.

Comment: I tried to add EnableDetailedErrors = true but that option is not available to .AddAzureSignalR() and adding it to .AddSignalR seems to make no difference as I got the same error as above.

Comment: I checked my lib and ended up updating my ver of the client-side js and now I am able to add new parameters

Answer (score 0):

I checked my lib and ended up updating my ver of the client-side js and now I am able to add new parameters